# Jenkins issues calling a project that connects to a remote SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, jenkins

I am running Jenkins 1.615 on windows 2008 R2 server. I have a few projects that connect to a remote database (to set various user accounts to expire for example) before the test starts. I keep seeing connection issues to the DB when the program is called in the jenkins console, however when I run the program on the system as administrator it works fine. Is there a plugin I need for my program (that connects to a remote database (that is being called by jenkins). Mainly my .NET clients that I wrote connect to various microsoft sql databases. The documentation on this in jenkins is vague but points to the case where you want to have jenkins update an internal database for reporting. Thanks

Comment: Can you supply the info for the connection issues from the console output?

Comment: via jenkins console
E:\jobs\DBtest\workspace>call "E:\SeleniumScripts\DBtest.bat" 
running script now
DBI connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=VMDEV-APPDB\XIPAY;Database=DI_SAP_UA;UID=<domain>\<user>; trusted_Connection=yes;','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. 
The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (SQL-28000) at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBHelpers.pm line 30.
CONNECT ERROR:

Comment: n the system running jenkins I can run the script just fine 

E:\SeleniumScripts>perl dbtest.pl
Connecting to the Database
Beginning Database updates
Running Sql: update dbo.Users set U_LastLogin = GetDate() where UID in (442) now
Finishing Database updates
Disconnecting from the Database

Comment: contents of C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBHelpers.pm line 30 is where I define a subroutine ( this is a perl db module I wrote to connect to a test results database (that is remote from the jenkins server) to update test results)
sub DBConnect {

 my ($db_instance,$db_name,$db_user) = @_;

 print "\nConnecting to the Database\n";
 sleep($sleeptime);

 $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$db_instance;Database=$db_name;UID=$db_user; trusted_Connection=yes;") or die("\n\nCONNECT ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr"); 
 
 } # end DBConnect Function

Comment: Can you add the content to your answer and format it nicely there?